# CopyLZFileName/CreateLZFileName.. what does LZ means?

Tags: windows, kernel

I am gathering small information regarding kernel dll functions.. and I found this function called `CopyLZFileName`/`CreateLZFileName` and some other functions related to this LZ.. I googled for it.. I cant find a proper source for it. From the name I guess it copies/creates file but am not sure what kind of file.. does LZ mean something to it. Please let me know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I always thought LZ stood for "Lempel-Ziv", inventors of most popular compression algorithms (LZ77, LZ78, LZW) used nowadays. As far as I remember these API functions had been used for creating singly compressed files (aka `COMMAND.CO_` style file naming), before .CAB format kicked in.

Comment: Thanks! I remember too. Utility to decompress such files were called `expand`. Very interesting why google has zero references to this functions?!

Answer (score 1):

Because `lz32.dll` is `32-bit compression routines` I think `LZ` stands for `Library Zip`

Comment: thanks for your reply..can you tell me what does that function actually do?

Comment: @kiddo: I can't find any reference to function names you specified. I found only `LZCopy` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365223%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: @kiddo: I think that `LZCopy` is really a replacement for `CopyLZFileName` because I found next: "The LZCopy function copies a source file to a destination file. If the source file is compressed with the Microsoft File Compression Utility (COMPRESS.EXE), this function creates a decompressed destination file." http://www.answers.com/topic/lzcopy